# How center text in absolute div inside td?

Tags: html, css

In my project, there is a html table which each td contains a div. I have to set that div to fit the td, so I set the position of td to relative and div to absolute.

please consider the following table and its style:

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
}
table td div {
  position: absolute;
  backgroundcolor: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>a1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>b2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>c2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>a2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>b2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>c2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above styled table is just perfect to fulfill what I expected for. Next, I want to set the text in the absolute div to be center (include vertically).

So I found it around the internet, most of them is suggesting to give that div with a `display: table;` style. Obviously, it fails :(

Can any tell me how to center those text?

Comment: can anyone help me to give it a live demo?

Comment: setting td to relative has no effect mate, gotta try something else. Why do you place a div inside cell at all? It is easy to center text inside td itself.

Comment: @skobaljic my project is a event calendar, div is more useful in my case.

Comment: Again, setting relative position to table cell has **no effect** to rendering, it does not work. Just set `#theTable td {vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}`

Comment: @skobaljic how to make the div filling the td? i have a hover effect for the div

Comment: Do hover effect on **td** mate, try to think other way around. There is no way to make your div fullfill the cell, unless you know the cell's height in front (or to set your div some fixed height, or to use script). I would suggest (if you are allowed) - change the layout to flex.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center;` to css `table td div{ ... }`

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9kznm317/

Comment: o sorry, i am also asking vertically center

Answer (score 0):

You can put some `0-width inline-block` element and set it's `vertical-align` to `middle`, like the code bellow shows:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
table td div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
table td div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* just for demo */
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>a1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>b2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>c2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>a2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>b2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>c2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Setting relative position to td has no effect. What you did in this example is: 1. set td height to 100px, than set child element height to 100% - it has nothing to do with relative/absolute positioning.

Comment: @skobaljic But if removing `relative` than `absolute` element will take it's position and dimensions from closest non-static element -> html

Comment: Setting `relative` to table cell is not defined, it does not work - hope it is clear now.

Comment: @skobaljic How to set absolute position inside `td` if it's `relative` *does not work*?

Comment: There is no way to do it using `relative`, that's what OP tried to do. It is not that it does not work, but is **not defined for table elements at all**. As specified: `The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined`. Could be it works in some browsers, or browser versions, but it should not.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{width:500px;height:600px;}
table td {
  position: relative;
  
}
table td div{
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
table td div span {
 display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div><span>a1</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>b2</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>c2</span></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div><span>a2</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>b2</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>c2</span></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's a must? I think the question is how to center the text.

Comment: @king yau in that case, the only solution is to wrap text with other tag. I've used a span. That will work for you?